# Bootstrap Carousel is not working in my website

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am creating a website based on PHP & Bootstrap. I am trying to add a bootstrap carousel on my webpage using the following code but it is not working fine. But it works in the JS Fiddle. Below is the link to my website.

```
https://app1.unotechcloud.com/cbd/new-index.php
```

Please check and suggest a solution. There is already an owl slider, working perfectly on the website. But none carousel code is working fine.

`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-family: georgia;
}

.parent {
  background: url("https://localtvkfor.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/91.jpg?w=2000") center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -100;
}

.wrapper1,
.wrapper1 .row {
  height: 100%;
}

.child {
  background-color: rgba(220, 220, 220, 0.5);
  padding: 18px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid parent">

</div>


<div class="container wrapper1">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12-xs child">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators hidden-xs">
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <!--    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>-->
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner hidden-xs" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img src="https://cbd-inhalers.com/img/cbd-soft-gels-img.png" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img src="https://cbd-inhalers.com/img/cbd-soft-gels-img.png" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img src="https://cbd-inhalers.com/img/cbd-soft-gels-img.png" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
                </a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-4">
                <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">Lorem ipsum dolor.</div>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like this

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y328A.png)

Comment: Do you mean the "owl"carousel  in the banner section?? - i went to your site and it is working. Both auto rotating images and alloowing navigation back and forth on clicking the next / prev. If there is a nother carousel on the page -that is not working then it is probably because of clashing with this one - but the hero carousel is working.

Comment: its working only

Comment: I mean the product carousel section, wrapped in wrapper1 CSS class. I am not talking about the banner slider. Please scroll down.